# Removing stop words from String

Tags: java, words

```
class MyClass {
public static void remove_stopwords(String[] query, String[] stopwords) {
    A: for (int i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
        B: for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.length; j++) {
             C: if (query[i].equals(stopwords[j])) { 
                    break B;
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println(query[i]);
                    break B;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

For some reason this code only works correctly about halfway through the problem. It takes the first stopword out of the query, but it ignores the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: provide us with a example with query, stopwords and desired result

Comment: query: ["do","not","drop","the","soap"]
stopwords: ["do","the"]
desired output:
not
drop
soap

my output:
not
drop
the
soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 class MyClass 
 {
    public static void remove_stopwords(String[] query, String[] stopwords) {

        A: for (int i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
            //iterate through all stopwords
            B: for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.length; j++) {
                    //if stopwords found break
                    C: if (query[i].equals(stopwords[j])) { 
                        break B;
                    } 
                    else { 
                        // if this is the last stopword print it
                        // it means query[i] does not equals with all stopwords
                        if(j==stopwords.length-1)
                        {
                           System.out.println(query[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've been messing around with that for the past hour or so actually. removing that break statement gives me the following output:
not not drop drop the soap soap

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding stop word in arraylist and tried to compare with stringarray to remove if any stop word is found. But ia m finding some problem in my loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> stopWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        stopWords.add("that");
        stopWords.add("at");
        String sentence = "I am not that good at coder";
        String[] SentSplit = sentence.split(" ");
        System.out.println(SentSplit.length);
        StringBuffer finalSentence = new StringBuffer();
        boolean b = false;

        for(int i=0; i<stopWords.size();i++){
            String stopWord = stopWords.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j<SentSplit.length;j++){
                String word = SentSplit[j];
                if(!stopWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
                    finalSentence.append(SentSplit[j] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalSentence);
    }
```

Expected result is: `I am not good coder`

But my result is: `I am not good at coder I am not that good coder`